# codeigniter substract two variables from two different loop

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello guys i need to find the differences between two different loops which is summation loop and totals loop as shown in controller code below

```
function summary() {

        echo '<table>';


            $summation=$this->select_model->sum_income("date_of_income BETWEEN '" . $start . "' AND '" . $last . "'");

                 foreach($summation as $sum){


                echo '<tr><td>Total Income</td> <td >'.$sum['total'].'</td></tr>';

                    } 




            $totals=$this->select_model->sum_expenditure("date_of_expenditure BETWEEN '" . $start . "' AND '" . $last . "'");

                    foreach($totals as $total){

                    echo '<tr><td>Total Expenditure</td><td ><strong>'.$total['total'].'<</td></tr>'; 

                    }
                    //display differences here:
                    echo '<tr><td>'.**$sum['total']-$total['total']**.'</td></tr>'

        echo '</table>';


        }
```

Comment: And we should help you with what?

Comment: how can substract $total['total'] from $sum['total'] outside loop

Comment: You can't do it. Foreach is used to call each element of array, of course `$total` and `$sum` both are aliases. Outside `foreach`, it's unknown. Try other way.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create the variables outside of the loops and add (or subtract) as the loop progresses.

```
$sum = 0;
$total = 0;

foreach... {
    $sum += $sum;
}

foreach... {
    $total += $total;
}

echo $sum - $total;
```

If you're adding negative numbers, the math will work without having to do anything specific.